# Synchronous ajax requests by recursive loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to send a newsletter mail to a lot of receivers by making ajax requests to a script that sends the mail. In order to make sure that the previous request is finished (so that the maximum number of concurrent requests of the browser is not reached), I use a recursive loop function.

This question has already been asked a couple of times in different variants, but I could not find any answer that helps me out.

What I've tried:

```
var receiverarray = <?php echo json_encode($receiverarray); ?>; // All data is correctly received from PHP
var nrofreceivers = '<?php echo count($receiverarray); ?>';
nrofreceivers = parseInt(nrofreceivers);
function sendmailreceivers(receiverarray, callback) {
    try  {
        var a = 0;
        recur_loop(a);
        function recur_loop(i) {
            var num = i;
            if (num < nrofreceivers) {
                var count = num + 1;
                var percentage = (count / receiverarray.length) * 100;
                percentage = Math.round(percentage);
                var loadingtext = String(count) + " van " + String(nrofreceivers) + " (" + String(percentage) + "%)";
                $('#loadingtext').html(loadingtext);
                var thisreceiverarray = receiverarray[num];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://www.domain.com/scripts/sendmail.php", // Script works fine
                    data: {
                        'from_mail': '<?php echo $webmastermailaddress; ?>',
                        'from_name': 'Webmaster name',
                        'to_mail': thisreceiverarray.email,
                        'to_name': thisreceiverarray.name,
                        'reply_name': 'Business name',
                        'reply_mail': 'Business mail address',
                        'diff_mailer': '',
                        'mail_content': '<HTML>The html mail content</HTML>',
                        'mail_subject': '<?php echo $subject; ?>'
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        recur_loop(count);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        throw "Error!";
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        callback();
    }
    catch(err) {
        throw "Error!";
    }
}
```

This works fine for the first 3 mail addresses. Then for an unknown reason the function finishes and the callback makes sure the next function is executed (where I redirect the user to a thank you page).

So it looks like every mail has been sent, because the function finishes without error, but in fact only 3 mails are sent.

I've already spent a lot of days in looking for answers and trying to resolve it, but with no luck. There are no errors in the console?

Why is the function finishing prematurely?

Comment: The code appears to work as expected with simulated requests. What do you see in the network tab of the dev console? How many requests are actually sent? Might the problem be on the server side, i.e., the requests are being sent but not processed by the mail server? Without more details all one can do is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to improve your code a little bit, it's still not perfect:

```
var receiverarray = <?php echo json_encode($receiverarray); ?>;

function sendmailreceivers(callback) {
    try {
        recur_loop(0);
        function recur_loop(i) {
            if (i === receiverarray.length) {
              return callback();
            }
            var percentage = Math.round((i / receiverarray.length) * 100);
            var loadingtext = i + " van " + receiverarray.length + " (" + percentage + "%)";
            $('#loadingtext').text(loadingtext);
            var thisreceiverarray = receiverarray[i];
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://www.domain.com/scripts/sendmail.php", // Script works fine
                data: {
                    'from_mail': '<?php echo $webmastermailaddress; ?>',
                    'from_name': 'Webmaster name',
                    'to_mail': thisreceiverarray.email,
                    'to_name': thisreceiverarray.name,
                    'reply_name': 'Business name',
                    'reply_mail': 'Business mail address',
                    'diff_mailer': '',
                    'mail_content': '<HTML>The html mail content</HTML>',
                    'mail_subject': '<?php echo $subject; ?>'
                },
                success: function(){
                    recur_loop(i + 1);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch(err) {
        callback(err);
    }
}

sendmailreceivers(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
        alert('Error!');
    } else {
        alert('Done');
    }
});
```

A few remarks:

- you called `callback` before the  first request was completed
- `try { ... } catch(err) { throw "Error"; }` will swallow a meaningful error message and replace it with "Error" - not very useful.
- better use `.text(str)` instead of `.html` if `str` contains text not html code
- it's generally a good idea to add `err` as first argument for callback functions to return possible errors.
- `String(val)` and `parseInt(val, 10)` are only necessary to convert the type of values
- Other than in older PHP versions you don't need to store everything in a variable before you can use it. For example passing the return value of a function as an argument is totally fine.

Comment: Why not an answer? `you called callback before the first request was completed` plus code how to call it after all requests are completed?!

Comment: Hi all, Thanks already for your response! I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: It is working! And especially this part was the solution: 
    `if (i === receiverarray.length) {
        return callback();
    }`
Thanks!